# Qt style sheet syntax doesn't work?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I'm using Qt 5.0.1 . I want to use style sheet syntax to customize the features of widget and it's elements.

but some syntaxes like `QLineEdit { color: red }` or

```
QPushButton#evilButton:pressed {
     background-color: rgb(224, 0, 0);
     border-style: inset;
 }
```

don't work and compiler gives error.

I changed some syntaxes and got answer.for example:

```
QPushButton#evilButton {
 background-color: red;
 border-style: outset;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border-color: beige;
 font: bold 14px;
 min-width: 10em;
 padding: 6px;
```

}

converted to:

```
mypushbutton->setStyleSheet("background-color:purple;"
                     "border-style:inset;"
                     "border-width: 4px;"
                     "border-color: green;"
                     "border-radius: 10px;"
                     "font: bold 14px;"
                     "min-width: 10em;"
                     "padding: 6px;"
                     );
```

in fact I used another function to do that.but I couldn't change the first codes and don't know what to do...what should I do?should I `include` something or something else is the problem?I used [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/stylesheet-examples.html) page to learn the style sheet syntax.even the example of my own Qt aren't work and just error raises...!!!???

Comment: no one can answer my question?it is too necessary...please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tried your example and it works on Qt5

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->setStyleSheet(
                "QPushButton#evilButton {"
                "background-color: red;"
                "border-style: outset;"
                "border-width: 2px;"
                "border-radius: 10px;"
                "border-color: beige;"
                "font: bold 14px;"
                "min-width: 10em;"
                "padding: 6px; }"
                );
}
```

btw I store qss in file and load styles from it

Comment: forgot to say. You can setup qss for whole application

qApp->setStyleSheet("<your qss>");